# After installing Ubuntu windows got directly booted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I had windows 10 installed earlier and I wanted Ubuntu20.04 so
I use RUFUS for using USB to make it bootable for ubuntu20.04.
I selected partitioning scheme as MBR ,File system as FAT32 , target system as BIOS and UEFI ,
cluster size as 8192 bytes .
Installation went normal
where I used partitioning scheme as :
/ = 10gb
swap = 8gb
/home = 92gb
And installed bootloader on drive "sda" and not overwritten it with windows bootloader ,
Afterward when installation completed and I restarted laptop it directly botted into windows.
Uefi and legacy mode is enabled in my system .
when pressed esc button just after starting laptop and pressed f9 for boot options, where I got boot menu with two options as ubuntu , when I selected , then I got the screen with grub bootloader where Options were 1.ubuntu 2.advanced ubuntu 3.windows bootloader 4.firmware settings. I want choice at boot time . what should I do??

Comment: What do you want to achieve?  Boot directly in Ubuntu or in Windows or have the choice at boot time?

Comment: I want choice at boot time